# systemd custom message in journald

Tags: linux, systemd, journal

Is there a way we can modify systemd messages which go in journalctl
when a service is started or goes down? For example, currently the
message we get in journalctl when a service goes down is like this:

> Unit foo.service has finished shutting down.

Can this be logged as:

> foo.service dead. Nevermind, it wasn't doing anything as such

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Many systemd messages are controlled through the "locale" system. You can make a copy of a locale file and modify it to create your own and then set the system locale to the custom locale.

The locale files are stored in `/usr/lib/systemd/catalog/systemd`.

See `man localectl` and `man locale.conf` for more information on locale management.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. But I couldn't find how to set new systemd messages. There is locale.LC_MESSAGES=, option. I can't make out how that will work.

Comment: You set new systemd messages by following the advice in the answer: create a new locale based on an existing one, change it as you wish, and then start using the new locale.